# How to save score in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am stuck with the following problem: I have a fishing game. So far, if I play the game, I can start fishing, catch 2,3,4 more fish and everything is fine.

However, if I want to pause the game (Pressing ESC or a button that I placed in the scene) my score resets. Additionally, I don't know how to save my score, even if I pause the game or go into shop button.

Start function

```
void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Pesti");
    NrPesti.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Pesti").ToString();

    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Viermisori");
    NrViermisori.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Viermisori").ToString();

    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
    Score.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString();

    PlaySound(0);
}
```

Update function:

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(NrViermisori.text);
    Debug.Log(NrPesti.text);
    Debug.Log(Score.text);
    if (NrPesti.name =="Pesti")
    {
        NrPesti.text = "Lovers: " + NrPesti.text;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("NrPesti", NrPesti.text);
   if(NrViermisori.name == "Viermisori")
    {

        NrViermisori.text = "Beasts: " + NrViermisori.text;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Viermisori", NrViermisori.text);


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) Application.Quit();

}
```

Comment: I don't see anything to handle the scenario when you Save the score to PlayerPrefs.

Comment: Maybe because you aren't setting the value of `Pesti` anywhere? Plus you are not saving the PlayerPrefs.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html

Answer (score 1):

In your update method try adding something to your code where you are detecting Escape Press.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){ 
    PlayerPrefs.setInt("Score", Int32.Parse(Score.text));
    //Verify property is saved
    Int scoreTest = PlayerPrefs.getInt("Score");
    Debug.Log(scoreTest);
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the right way to save/load your score by doing operations on the `Text.text` directly.
If you want to save and load your score, make a separate variable `score` to store your score, then use your score in your UI Elements.
For example, this explains how you save scores at runtime:

```
public class Score: MonoBehaviour {

    public int score = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // get the score when this gameObject initialized
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // this is how you set your score to PlayerPrefs
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", score);
        }
    }

    // this is an public function to be used 
    // outside of the class to update score
    public void UpdateScore(int amount) {
        score += amount;
    }
}
```

And use your score in your UI class:

```
public class DisplayScore : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text scoreText;
    public Score playerScore;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // get your Score component here or just drag it in inspector
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // this updates the score at every frame
        scoreText.text = playerScore.score.ToString();
    }
}
```

don't forget `using UnityEngine.UI`, saving/loading score in this way will be much easier.

Usually, you don't need to call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` since the data will be automatically written to disk when the game quits (it calls automatically in `OnApplicationQuit()`), but you may want to call it at certain point (*i.e checkpoints*) in case of program crushes or other unexpected situations.

Comment: I still don t understand how can i do it.

Comment: @StefanSmarandache you need to understand how `PlayerPrefs` works, `PlayerPrefs` which stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions. You can store a variable in a scene giving it a key and a value, and access the value in another scene with the key you given. You can read the documentation about `PlayerPrefs` here: (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html )

Answer (score 0):

You should have a kind of a `GameManager` class where you store everything you need to remember in appropriate `attributes`. When you start the game you create an instance of the GM and reference to this object in the game logic. Things like the Score should be stored and processed within the GM. That way you can make sure to 'save' your score while the game is alive.