# TotalScore system in unity game development

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have written this script to get score and this script is working fine but whenever i end the game or the game is over scorecount resets to 0 and when i rerun my game it starts to count from 0 again while i want it to remember my last point and starts to count from where i left. I mean it should be like lifetime total score.

Here's my code sample:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ShackUp : MonoBehaviour 
{

public Text scoreText;


private int scoreCount = 0;

private void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
        OnbackButtonPressed ();

    if (gameOver)
        return;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        if (PT ())
        {               
            SpawnTile ();
            scoreCount++;
            scoreText.text = scoreCount.ToString ();
        }
        else
        {
            EndGame ();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 2D: PlayerPrefs Implementation for Highscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732301/unity-2d-playerprefs-implementation-for-highscore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save score in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252950/how-to-save-score-in-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several solutions to do that.

The easiest is to use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).
With PlayerPrefs, you allow Unity to persist the data to disk.

To save a value, do the following:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Score", scoreCount);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

And to read it later:

```
var score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score");
```

This is a good solution for preferences values and small data (like your score).

If you need to store a bigger chunk of data, another solution would be to save your data to a file. To get the path to a folder that Unity knows it has access to, whatever the platform is, get the [persistantDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) like this:

```
Application.persistantDataPath
```

Finally you could consider using a server or a database if you really had lots of data or if you need it to be saved online, but I guess that is not what you ask right now so I won't develop it here

**EDIT, example in your code, using a property so that ScoreCount is saved in playerPrefs**

```
public class ShackUp : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Text scoreText;


    private int ScoreCount 
    {
        get{ return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", 0); }
        set{ PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", value); }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
            OnbackButtonPressed ();

        if (gameOver)
            return;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
        {
            if (PT ())
            {               
                SpawnTile ();
                ScoreCount++;
                scoreText.text = ScoreCount.ToString ();
            }
            else
            {
                EndGame ();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Here are some precision following your comment

1) For your understanding about **c# properties**: 
Yes, we could replace the variable scoreCount in your script by the line `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score")`. This would work. But in this example I did something a bit different: I used a **property**. It is declare like this:

```
    private int ScoreCount 
    {
        get{ return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", 0); }
        set{ PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", value); }
    }
```

See, it is like a variable: it is private, it is an int, it has the name ScoreCount (The convention is to use uppercase letter at the beginning for these but it is not mandatory)
Then, instead of giving this variable a value, I give it the **accessors**: a get like this `get{ return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", 0); }` This means that anytime you write something like `int a = ScoreCount`, it will actually call `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", 0);` for you, so you don't have to write it.

The setter works in the same way. In the set part of a property, you always have access to a variable called **value**. So if in your code you write `ScoreCount = 3`, it will actually call `set{ PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", value); }` with the number 3 in the `value` variable.

You can read more about properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

So to conclude, you **could** call

```
scoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString ()
```

But this will do the same

```
scoreText.text = ScoreCount.ToString ()
```

2)

About adding some text to a string. This is called string concatenation 
and the doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings)

To summarize, here are two ways you can do it.

Add the strings with a '+' operator. Since "+" is a string, adding an int works and give a string, so you don't need to write toString anymore:

```
scoreText.text = "+" + ScoreCount
```

A bit more complicated but useful to know if you need more complex string formatting latter, use the string.Format [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
scoreText.text = String.Format("+{0}", ScoreCount)
```

This replace {0} by ScoreCount. You caould add more variable using {1}, {2} ...

Comment: While PlayerPrefs are used in many cases as an easy way to store things, they also are stored in less than ideal places, such as on Windows in the registry system, where they can be edited.

But for a small non-online experiment they work.

Comment: Yep, it is true that they can be edited, and that's why it is suitable for preferences (that are user editable anyway). Some libraries exist to encrypt it if needed as well (see https://github.com/rawandnf/SecurePlayerPrefs for example)

Comment: A score is not a preference. A preference is a setting. You cannot edit your score normally as that would render it useless.

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud i didn't get it properly can you show me editing my code?

Comment: @Doh09 yes, I know that, thanks. Isn't it clear that OP wants an easy way to persist and that PlayerPrefs are a good start (exaclty like you said in your comment)? You said they are not ideal because editable, I say it fits well for preferences. This is a discussion beyond the scope of this question about score. In this specific case we agree that OP can use it because it is easy, and if needed he can use encrypted playerprefs

Comment: I never said that your mentioned solution wasn't worth suggesting. I just attached extra information to it so that he can make his decision on a broader foundation of knowledge. I also didn't say it wasn't ideal, because I leave that up to OP to decide, I said the location the values are stored is less than ideal.

All i've done is to add information and correct the statement that a score is a preference.

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud Thank you for your support... one last thing i need to know... is as i got to know that PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", value); is the way to save my score and to show it in my game i need to write scoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score").ToString (); and it'll show my saved value in the scoreText field. I just want to show +sing before the value like if my saved value is 26, in the  scoreText field i want it to show like +26 to show this + sign what should i do?